# Is it possible to convert a simple grails application to OSGi bundle that can run in Adobe CQ?

Tags: grails, osgi, osgi-bundle, sling, grails-2.2

I have a simple `Grails 2.2.4` application that simply lists a bunch of items on a page. So I only have one controller and I'm not even using the database.

Now, I want to convert this application into an OSGi sling bundle so that I can run it under Adobe CQ.

when I prepare the Grails app it creates a WAR file...how can I tweak it such that it creates a war/jar file that is an OSGi bundle?

As an example, I came across this [Slingbucks](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/samples/slingbucks/) example. I was able to built it (JAR) and upload the JAR to Adobe CQ and I was able to run it inside Adobe CQ.

**Question**

I'm wondering if there is a way to tweak a Grails app such that can be run as a bundle in Adobe CQ

Comment: see amended answer for 2014 plugin link

Answer (score 2):

first install the [grails osgi plugin](https://github.com/jetztgradnet/grails-osgi-plugin)  or the [jira grails plugin](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2221) (more recent)

```
  grails install-plugin osgi
```

then you can follow the instructions at the [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/OSGi+and+Groovy) site to convert it to a jar.

Comment: Thanks. I came across the grails osgi plugin but it seems to not have been updated since 2010. I also read some comments that it doesn't work well with grails 2. Just wondering if you've tried it before or have experience with it?

Comment: no i know it hasn't been updated but it still comes recommended. I haven't used it myself.

Comment: there is an alternative https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2221 updated 2014